# Node.js Forever Monitor Install Warning

Tags: node.js, npm, forever

I just installed forever monitor with npm. It installed successfully.. i think.

```
npm install forever-monitor
npm WARN package.json admin@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
.
.
.
npm WARN engine forever-monitor@1.1.0: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.0","npm":"1.2.14"})
```

Whats up with the WARN lines?

Answer (score 0):

Publishing NPM package requires adding a README file to help people understand the package. But many smaller packages which are used in bigger packages don't have these readme files. I wouldn't worry too much about it if the main package you are installing works properly and can be relied on.